# C: structs in structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My assignment is to create a simple graph that has both Nodes and Edges.
In my header file which was given and cant't be modified I have

```
typedef struct Edge_s* Edge;
typedef struct Node_s* Node;
typedef struct Graph_s* Graph;
```

and in my graph.c

```
typedef struct{
  size_t w;
  struct Node_s* target;
}*Edge;

typedef struct{
  size_t value;
  Edge* edges;
  size_t s;
}*Node;

typedef struct{
  Node* nodes;
  size_t n;
  Edge* edges;
  size_t e;
}*Graph;

Edge create_edge(Node t, size_t w){
  Edge ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret));
  ret->target = t;
  ret->w = w;
  return ret;
}
```

This gives a warning on compile

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

I'm kind of confused here, what am I getting wrong and how should I fix it? The program is almost working and I'm getting one strange bug that I believe might be because of this.

Comment: Am I reading that correctly? Each `Edge` has exactly one `Node` `target`?

Comment: Agreed. If this were my code to maintain long-term, I'd get rid of all those typedefs and be done with it. It's not like typing `struct Node` is so much worse than `Node`.

Comment: If the teacher gave him/her a header file with typedefs, I would recommend not changing the typedefs.  Part of doing well in school is in giving the answers the way the teachers want to get them, just as part of doing well in work is performing your tasks the way your employer wants them done.

Comment: When posting questions like this, it is helpful if we know exactly which line the compiler flagged.  Don't worry about it now, since AndreyT already solved the problem, but please keep it in mind for future questions.

Comment: I'd be hard pressed to make an assignment of 18 tokens that was more confusing to a tyro. I'm hoping that wasn't intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your typedef-definitions are mixed up badly. I'm surprised it even compiles.

You first defined typedef-name `Edge` as

```
typedef struct Edge_s* Edge;
```

and then later re-defined it as

```
typedef struct{
  size_t w;
  struct Node_s* target;
}*Edge;
```

These two definitions define `Edge` in two completely unrelated ways. (All C compilers I know would immediately report an error if the first group of declarations would meet the the second group in the same translation unit.)

I'd say that your second struct definition should be simply

```
struct Edge_s {
  size_t w;
  struct Node_s* target;
};
```

Don't attempt to redefine an existing typedef-name. It is simply illegal in C.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Weird thing is it compiled and ran just fine. The small bug is still there though...

Comment: And the bug was due to not reading the assignment properply :/

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself what type of object does ret->target point to and what type of object is it?  Are they the same types of objects?

Comment: Doesn't this line mean `Edge` _is_ a pointer? `typedef struct Edge_s* Edge;` (Incidentally, I hate `typedef`s that mask the fact that something is a pointer. Hate.)

Comment: Oh, geez, I overlooked that.  And yes, I also HATE typedefs that mask pointers.  Pointers should always be obvious.  Edited to fix.  Thanks.

Comment: Aren't they both of type struct Node_s* which has been deftyped as Node?

Comment: @Odingod: As AndreyT pointed out, your typedefs are mixed up badly, making this very deceptive code.

Comment: @sarnold but that's how you get data encapsulation in C

Comment: @GradGuy: If I wanted data encapsulation I'd pick a different language. :) Seriously, it's not so bad to hand users a `struct foo` and tell them to not poke around inside.

Comment: @sarnold later on, on the user side: MUST ... RESIST ... POKING ... AROUND :p. I agree though that C is not the best you could use for OOP, but I have seen some very nice codes written this way :). It's a matter of taste I guess ;)